# Publish Content in Drupal by One Editor Only

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system

Im a new Admin for an Educational E learning Portal Developed by drupal,
the current status of publishing a Content is to be verified or reviewed by two Moderators or Editors.
My Question is : How to make (1) Editor publish a content after Reviewing instead of 2?

The Current flow, A "teacher" publish an Educational Content as ( needs review: , then an Editor Reviews that content and then he chooses ONE OF THE FOLLOWING: 1) initial approve 2) send back to Edit " to the teacher" 3) Publish - BUT in order to publish another Editor must review and Publish it to be available as a published content.

the used workflow is the default workbench Flow, But nothing there mentions that 2 Editors must Review,

where can i Find such a code to edit? in which module Block ?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi there. We'll probably need a lot more details about how the site is set up for publishing content currently – how the modules involved in the publishing workflow are configured, for example – as well as possibly relevant code that goes with it. Depending on if this ends up being more about the module PHP or other configuration settings, this question may be better suited for the Drupal-specific Stack Exchange site: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you so much,

Comment: The Current flow, A "teacher" publish an Educational Content as ( needs review: , then an Editor Reviews that content and then he chooses ONE OF THE FOLLOWING:
1) initial approve
2) send back to Edit " to the teacher"
3) Publish - BUT in order to publish another Editor must review and Publish it to be available as a published content.

thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Mohammed. Go ahead and edit your question to include this information. Another good detail to include would be what module(s) you are using to power this workflow, or if it is a custom module. If it's a custom module, you should include the part of the code relevant to what you are trying to edit in the question as well. I probably won't be able to answer this question for you, but if you include all that info in your question, someone else who comes along may be able to help you out.

Comment: will edit now .. thanks.

Comment: Drupal by default doesn't have a workflow like that for publishing, i guess you site is using a module to implement that workflow, maybe Workflow. and Rules. Try to provide more data about the modules that your site is using (or the elearning distribution that you are using, maybe opingo?). If is using workflows You can take a look to this https://www.drupal.org/node/550716 ... if you don't have idea what I'm talking, you might need help from your IT department or developer.